# Установка i-го параметра в шаблоне

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, шаблоны-с++

Есть класс, у которого все параметры шаблона имеют значение по умолчанию:

```
template<class T1 = t1, ..., class Ti = ti, ..., class Tn = tn>
class A {
    // ...
};
```

Как установить значение для параметра Ti, а значения остальных параметров оставить по умолчанию?

```
A<Ti = int> a; // как-то так хотелось бы
```

**UPD**

Будет здорово, если удастся найти решение, которое позволит задавать произвольное количество аргументов, а остальные оставлять по умолчанию:

```
A<Ti = int, Tj = float, ...> a;
```

Comment: Без кучи вспомогательных `using` деклараций — никак.

Comment: @ixSci вы имеете ввиду запомнить значения по умолчанию с помощью `using`?

Comment: Я имел в виду кучу `using` тип `AArg1`, `AArg2`, где каждый из этих using повторяет оригинальный шаблон полностью, но позволяет задать лишь один аргумент, который должен отличаться от того, что по умолчанию.

Comment: @ixSci тогда нельзя будет задать два аргумента: `A<Ti=int, Tj=float> a;`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть одно решение, правда использует оно [Boost.Hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html). 
Удобства:

- Расширяемость: можно добавлять в конец новые шаблонные параметры
- Конструкция пишется один раз, нет смысла в куче `using`ов
- Никакого overhead'а, доступ к параметрам остался, все проверки во время компиляции

На Ваш суд:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <class _Args = decltype(hana::tuple_t<int, float, double>)> // параметры по умолчанию - int, float, double
class BaseA {

public:
    using Args = _Args;

    template <size_t N> // для доступа к аргументам шаблона
    using Arg = typename decltype(+Args{}[hana::size_c<N>])::type;
};

template <class Type, size_t Pos> // тип, который хотим поменять, и его позиция
using fix_A_arg = BaseA<decltype(hana::insert(hana::remove_at(BaseA<>::Args{}, hana::size_c<Pos>), hana::size_c<Pos>, hana::type_c<Type>))>;

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {    
    using A = BaseA<>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<A::Arg<0>, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<A::Arg<1>, float>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<A::Arg<2>, double>);

    using B = fix_A_arg<bool, 0>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<B::Arg<0>, bool>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<B::Arg<1>, float>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<B::Arg<2>, double>);

    using C = fix_A_arg<struct Foo, 1>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<C::Arg<0>, int>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<C::Arg<1>, struct Foo>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<C::Arg<2>, double>);

    return 0;
}
```

[Онлайн-проверка](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iFB4F8IVpKVWzi2Y)

Answer (score 0):

в качестве бредовой идеи, а вдруг кто-то вдохновится

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T1 = int, typename T2 = int>
class sample {
    T1 x;
    T2 y;
};

template <std::size_t I, typename S>
auto sample_get() {
    if constexpr (I == 1) {
        return sample<S, int>();
    } else if constexpr (I == 2) {
        return sample<int, S>();
    }
}

int main() {
    auto x = sample_get<1, float>();
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
    auto y = sample_get<2, double>();
    std::cout << typeid(y).name() << std::endl;
}
```